# What the different between protected VS internal?

Tags: c#, .net

Despite all the explanations, I'm still trying to understand something.
The only difference between internal and protected is the use of it inside the project?

Thanks,

Tal

Comment: When you do not talk about accessibility modifiers for types ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers ) I have no idea what you talk about. Update your question. Where did you see a 'protected project'?

Comment: Apparently I didn't understand the question of my lecturer, he meant what the difference between protected and internal.. and this question i know the answer.. thanks try to help me :)

Comment: Glad to help u understand

Comment: Hi, Tal. You edited your existing question and turned it into a completely different question, losing the original one and making the existing answer irrelevant. You probably meant to create a new question - you can do that using the "Ask Question" button in the top right corner.

Comment: Tal, please don't *edit* the content of your question. Add a new comment, but don't rewrite the past.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan , Because the site no longer receives any questions from me, I saw that I had to edit my existing questions with a score 0 or less. link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans. This is what i do :)

Comment: Your accepted answer is correct to your current question. Do not edit your question to another question.

Comment: What you're doing is making sure your question ban is *extended*. You're essentially vandalizing your existing questions, making the existing answers wrong and useless to others. When the site tells you to edit existing questions, it means "in order to fix and improve them", not to use them for new questions.

Comment: OK thanks, i'll not doing this anymore

Comment: Edited my answer to give a sample of the accesibility modifiers. I think you struggle because one modifiers is related to inheritance (`protected`) and the other one is related to the structure of the classes withing the assemblies of the project (`internal`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there is not such thing as protected or internal projects.Projects contain classes and other type and are those elements inside the projects that can have different access modifiers.

Internal modifier: Can be referenced/accesed only within the same assembly (same .exe or .dll)

Protected modifier: Can be referenced/accesed from classes that inherit from him, the class that inherit it could potentially be in another assembly (for example, a protected method inside a public class, could be called only from another class that inherits from it, but that class could be in another assembly/project because the class was declared public).

There are also other accessibility modifiers, one of them I have just mentioned:

Public modifier: Can be referenced/accesed from classes from the same assembly or other assemblies.

Private modifier: Can be referenced/accesed from the same class it has been declared.

Example

```
Assembly/Project1

public class ClassA {
    private string variable1;
    protected string variable2;
    public string variable3;
    internal string variable4;

    public void MyFancyProcess()
    {
        Console.Write(variable1);
    }
}

public class ClassB : ClassA {
    public string variable5;

    private void DoSomeStuff()
    {
        Console.Write(variable1); // This would raise an error, its is private and only could be called from ClassA *even if ClassB is child of ClassA*
        Console.Write(variable2); // I can access variable2 because it is protected *AND ClassB is child of ClassA*
        Console.Write(variable3); // This would work, public has no restrictions
        Console.Write(variable4); // This would work, ClassB and ClassA share same assembly
    }
}

internal class ClassC
{
    ClassA myAClassInstance = new ClassA();

    Console.Write(myAClassInstance.variable1); // This would raise an error, it is exclusive to ClassA and we are in ClassC
    Console.Write(myAClassInstance.variable2); // This would raise an error, because ClassC does not inherit ClassA
    Console.Write(myAClassInstance.variable3);
    Console.Write(myAClassInstance.variable4); // This would work, ClassC and ClassA share same assembly
}
Assembly/ProjectB

public class ClassD : ClassA // Please note that if ClassA where not public it would raise an error
{
    public void ExecuteMyLogic()
    {
       Console.Write(variable1); // This would raise an error, its is private and only could be called from ClassA
        Console.Write(variable2); // I can access variable2 because it is protected *AND ClassD is child of ClassA despite being a different assembly*
        Console.Write(variable3); // This would work, public has no restrictions
        Console.Write(variable4); // This would raise an error, they are different assemblies
    }
}
```